# How to view RGB 565 format image on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, image-processing

Is there any tool on ubuntu to view RGB 565 format image?

If yes, can you please tell me how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

1. GIMP

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gimp
   ```
2. kolourpaint

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install kolourpaint4
   ```